# HTML/CSS: div, anchor and image tag with space below

Tags: html, css

**please read the full post before marking this as a duplicate**

We're all familiar with the annoying default agent stylesheet from browsers. We're probably also familiar with the annoying anchor and image tags with whitespace underneath it.

**So here's my issue:**

*HTML*:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="src">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="src">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="src">
    </a>
</div>
```

---

I used some social icons for test purposes and it looks like this:

[image]

---

I want the anchor to be a square, so in my CSS I simply say `a { display: inline-block; }`

[image]

---

But now there's a whitespace underneath the image, so in my CSS I say `img { display: block }`

[image]

---

Everything with the anchor tag and image tag seems to be fine now, but...

Now there's a whitespace inside the div, without there's any evidence it's either the anchor tag or the image tag.

[image]

---

You might think: "well that's easy. Just say `div { font-size: 0 }` in your CSS". Well that causes another issue: the div does not measure the height very well. It slices off one pixel on the top:

[image]

---

**So if there are any fixes:** how would I fix this without ugly fixes like: `padding-top: 1px` or `margin-bottom: ...px`

**If there are no fixes:** that would be weird

Comment: @caramba do you read?

Comment: css => a img {display:inline-block}

Comment: guys, please read carefully

Comment: I read my friend...

Comment: use `display:block` or `inline-block` to get `a` tag in square

Comment: @caramba yes, that did not solve my problem, as I explained in my question that I put the anchor tags to `display inline-block` and image tags to `display block` There is **no whitespace** below either the image or anchor tag (see the uploaded GIF), but inside the div tag. The answers on *the duplicate answer* did not solve my problen

Comment: @LKG already have that

Comment: Posted working example @DerkJanSpeelman

Comment: It's old but maybe it help some one.
I solved this by setting `a { display: inline-flex; }` for the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `a { float:left }` or `a { vertical-align: middle }`

Comment: That's interesting, now it slices off 1 pixel on the top **and** it still has the whitespace inside the div tag

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman try the update

Comment: `a { float: left }` does do the trick altough I need to wrap it up inside another div tag to align the icons to the center using `text-align: center`, but this does work indeed. `a { vertical-align: middle }` works as well, I discovered

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman will you accept then please :)

Comment: I requested an edit ready to be peer reviewed, than I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox works nice.

```css
div, a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but as I open the devtools I can see there is a whitespace inside the anchor tag. So this is not a fix

Comment: Than we use a nested flexbox. No more whitespace